# How to plot Arrhenius Equation in Maple to obtain a linear plot?

Tags: plot, graphics, computer-science, maple, chemistry

For the Arrhenius equation in Maple, I have the following code:

```
A := 0.9e10; 
Ea := 350; 
R := 0.8314e-2; 
lnk := ln(A)-Ea/(T*R);
plot(lnk, T = 1/100 .. 1/400);
```

that gives me the following plot:

[image]

but i am not getting a straight line plot like:

[image]

How can I write the code to get a straight line plot, as shown in the last plot (as it appears in the books)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A := 0.9e10:
Ea := 350:
R := 0.8314e-2:
lnk := ln(A)-Ea/(T*R):

plot([1/T, lnk, T = 100 .. 700],
     adaptive=false, numpoints=10,
     style=pointline, linestyle=dot,
     symbol=solidcircle, color="blue",
     axis[1]=[location=low],
     axis[2]=[gridlines,
              tickmarks=[seq(i=sprintf("%.2e",i),i=0..-450,-50)]],
     title="Arrhenius plot", 
titlefont = ["Helvetica", 14],
     font = ["Helvetica", 10],
     labels = ["1/T", "ln(k)"],
     labelfont = ["Helvetica", "bold", 16],
     labeldirections = [horizontal, vertical],
     axes=boxed, size=[600,400], view=[0..0.012,-450..0]);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited the question. I think that in essence it is to know how to graph the reciprocal of a variable in an equation, in this case on the right hand side we have -Ea / (RT), the variable is T. So in a graph, know how to graph 1 / T and not T.

Comment: I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: To Acer: Thanks for the tremendous answer, I was hoping for a help with just the straight line, but your answer really was much more comprehensive. Totally grateful